# getValues() returns REF error becuase dynamic field is not loaded yet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function which copies a whole sheet to another spreadsheet. The problem is that when executing getDataRange().getValues() it returns empty sheet with REF error in the first field. This is a normal behaviour when opening the spreadsheet because there is a dynamic function which takes usually couple seconds before the sheet is populated.

Is there any option how the script can "wait" for the sheet to load before returning the getValues()?

I tried getDisplayedValues() with the same result.

Thanks

I am expecting the getValues() to wait for the sheet to load fully.

Comment: What "dynamic function"?

Comment: Try using SpreadsheetApp.flush() before the getValues()

Comment: the dynamic functions consist of some indirect() and query() but all references are within the same spreadsheet, no importxml involved. The main issue is that it filters a sheet of 30 000+ rows, so it takes some seconds to display it..

Comment: the SpreadsheetApp.flush() miraculously helped!! Thanks a lot.